# A table was not created by _schema() function

Tags: database

I added this function to cleanetica_advanced module and after this ran /update.php

```
function cleanetica_advanced_schema() {
  $schema['videos'] = array (
    'description' => 'Videos with HTML titles',
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'description' => 'Primary key for our table of videos',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'urlinfo' => array(
        'description' => 'The string referring to the video',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => '255',
        'not null' => TRUE
      ),
      'title' => array(
        'description' => 'The title for a video, used in admin part only',
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'medium',
        'not null' => TRUE
      ),
      'richtitle' => array(
        'description' => 'The HTML-formatted title for a video',
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'medium',
        'not null' => TRUE
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

But the table `videos` was not created.

What have I missed in order for the table to be created?

The module cleanetica_advanced is enabled and I checked that it really loads by inserting a nonsense (non-PHP) there and seeing that the site crashes with an error. (After this I removed the nonsense.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hook_schema is only run for table creation during module install.

To run it later, you'd need to install the schema from .install file with something like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_update_N
 */
function cleanetica_advanced_update_7001(){
  drupal_install_schema('cleanetica_advanced');
}
```

Add, and then run update.php

Comment: And should my function cleanetica_advanced_schema() be defined in the .install file or in .module file?

Comment: in the .install file